# Dell laptop - hard drive failed

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I recently bought a new laptop from Dell. It's three months old and already the hard drive has failed. Luckily the data I lost was not too important. I've lost 3 weeks of data. I'm still under warranty and was wandering if Dell would replace it or try to recover my data. The hard drive has been taken out of the laptop twice to put into a different slot in the laptop.

I hope this doesn't affect the warranty because dell advertised the laptop as being easily customisable. So, will Dell replace the hard drive or help me recover the data?

Comment: Did you not have backups?

Comment: As I said I made a backup 3 weeks ago. I'm not 100% sure about failure but it failed tests and made weird noises. Now it's marked as offline in Intel rapid storage when I rebooted. It was part of a raid 0 with a 60gb ssd for cache.

Comment: Depends on what country you are in. I know for a fact Australia is pretty happy for you to remove the HDD and do recovery prior to getting Dell to replace the HDD (no Dell don't do data recovery to my knowledge, unless you have some warranty that somehow covers that). If you are in Indonesia, they put some sticker over all (or most) screw slots and if any one of them are damaged, warranty is void.

Comment: Dell isn't going to attempt to recover your data.  If you want that to happen best do it yourself.  All Dell will do is replace the HDD depending on the terms of your warranty.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I managed to get the drive working long enough to recover all the data from it. From now on I will back up more often. To get it to work I had to delete the raid configuration in raid bios (ctrl-I on boot).

Answer (score 1):

Dell has a warranty on the hardware. They do not have a warranty on the software, or any data.

Unless you removed the warranty sticker, pulling out a hard drive won't affect your warranty status.

You'll just need to contact dell.

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/topic.aspx/la/shared/support/en/warranty_information?c=us&l=en&s=gen&DoNotRedirect=y